# Merge two sorted linked lists in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, interview-questions, mergesort

Should I be using `std::move` or copy when passing `LNode` in the `LinkedList` constructor instead of passing by reference?

```
template <typename T>
struct LNode {
    T data;
    shared_ptr<LNode<T>> next;
    LNode(T p_data) : data(p_data) {}
    LNode() {}
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:

    LinkedList(LNode<T>& node) {
        root = make_shared<LNode<T>>(node);
    }

    LinkedList() {}

    void createAndLinkNodes(vector<T>& elements) {

        shared_ptr<LNode<T>> ptr = root;
        for (auto&& elem : elements) {
            shared_ptr<LNode<T>> node = make_shared<LNode<T>>(elem);
            ptr->next = node;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }

    }

    void mergeList(LinkedList<T>& list2)
    {
        auto ptr1 = root;
        auto ptr2 = list2.root;
        shared_ptr<LNode<T>> ptr3 = make_shared<LNode<T>>();
        auto tail = ptr3;

        while (ptr1!= nullptr && ptr2 != nullptr)
        {
            if(ptr1->data < ptr2->data) {
             appendNode(ptr1,tail);
            }
            else
            {
                appendNode(ptr2,tail);
            }
        }

        tail->next = ptr1 ? ptr1 : ptr2;
        root = ptr3->next;
    }

    void print() {
        shared_ptr<LNode<T>> ptr = root;
        while (ptr != nullptr)
        {
            cout << ptr->data << " ";
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

private:
    void appendNode(shared_ptr<LNode<T>> &node, shared_ptr<LNode<T>> &tail)
    {
        tail->next = node;
        tail = tail->next;
        node = node->next;
    }

private:
    shared_ptr<LNode<T>> root;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "MERGE SORTED LINKED LISTS" << endl;
    LNode<int> r1(2);
    LNode<int> r2(3);

    LinkedList<int> list1(r1);
    LinkedList<int> list2(r2);

    vector<int> elements1 = {5,7};
    vector<int> elements2 = {11};

    list1.createAndLinkNodes(elements1);
    list2.createAndLinkNodes(elements2);

    list1.print();
    list2.print();

    list1.mergeList(list2);
    list1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should make it at least `const LNode<T>& node` so someone can actually move a node into the constructor. You probably want to read about *perfect forwarding*. The book _Effective modern C++_ has a nice section on it.

Comment: Thank you, I will read that. Any other feedback is also appreciated.

Comment: `appendNode()` should probably be a member function of `LNode` of course this changes your code somehow because its more like `appendNodeAndNext()`. The first call of appendNode isn't correctly intended.